# Round to 25, 50, 75, 100

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I'm not a Math person so I'm having a hard time to come up with a calculation to round the decimals to 25, 50, 75 and 100. And this will not be the typical round off because the decimals will not be decreased but only increased.

Example:

if 11.12, round to 11.25

if 11.34, round to 11.50

if 11.52, round to 11.75

if 11.76, round to 12.00

Here's my starting method:

```
public float RoundNearestCents(String price)
    {
        float srp;

        return srp;
    }
```

Comment: Why is your price `string`? Also it is better to use `decimal` or even `int` to represent number of cents, but not `float`.

Comment: multiply by 4. Round to integer (use Math.Ceiling), Divide by 4.

Comment: @Ivan Grisenko. Because it's coming from a textbox. Really? Is there a decimal data type? Have never used it before, and also I think int doesn't support decimals

Comment: @Philip Sy, I assume you are not going to deal with fractional cents so `decimal` is a proper data type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public float RoundNearestCents(double d)
{
  return (double)(Math.Ceiling(d * 4)) / 4;
}
```

Comment: great answer but the syntax is wrong. it should be `(float)(Math.Ceiling(d * 4) / 4d)`.

Comment: Of all answers, this is the most simple. Thanks! :)

Comment: shouldn't that method be named to `RoundUpNearestQuater`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using types without floating point.

```
decimal RoundNearestCents(decimal price) {
    // no problems with floating point as all calculations are exact
    return Math.Floor((price * 100 + 24) / 25) * 25 / 100;
}
```

> -- Why is your price string?
>
> -- Because it's coming from a textbox.

I assume your textbox should support limiting your input to decimal numbers with at most 2 decimal places. So its value will be `decimal` already. However I don't know what is your application type. If you still want to accept `string` then consider using `decimal.TryParse` method to convert it to `decimal`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this:

```
float RoundNearestCents(float price)
    {
    price*=(100/25.0); // now fractions are going away
    if (price-floor(price)>=0.5) price++; // round up if fraction above 0.5
    return floor(price)*(25.0/100.0); // cut of the fraction and restore original range
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

My code may not be the best out there, but it will work.
In your function create a float and an int like so.

```
public float RoundNearestCents(String price)
{
    float srp = float.Parse(price);
    int srp1 = Int32.Parse(price);
    if((srp-srp1)>=0.5) 
        srp1++;
    else 
        return srp1;
    return srp1;
}
```

The int would truncate out the decimal part, which is like flooring the price.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
public decimal RoundNearestCents(decimal price)
{
    decimal srp = price * 100;
    decimal m = srp % 25;
    srp = srp - m + (m > 0 ? 25 : 0);
    return srp / 100;
}
```